# Nearby Search and Radar Search with name parameter consistently failing with "status": "ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: google-maps, google-places

I'm having an issue where the Places Search API returns ZERO_RESULTS on the m.site whatever the parameter. API Response attached. The search function had been working correctly until January when we began experiencing problems despite no change to the coding. I would appreciate any help. Thanks, Kyle.

```
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/PlaceService.FindPlaces?1m6&1m2&1d53.46731217725638&2d-2.2817558287549673&2m2&1d53.46731217725638&2d-2.2817558287549673&2sen-GB&3sphones%204u&6sstore&8e1&callback=_xdc_._7otmgw&token=86621 HTTP/1.1
Host: maps.googleapis.com
Referer: http://m.phones4u.co.uk/stores/my-phones4u-stores/53.46731217725638/-2.2817558287550095/?mweb=640-0-3
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-gb
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A525 Safari/8536.25


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2013 11:25:45 GMT
Server: mafe
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 115
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

_xdc_._7otmgw && _xdc_._7otmgw( {
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
 )
```

Comment: what is the query (or a query that produces these results)?

Comment: Hi Geocodezip. In short, every query that we have tried. This includes postcodes to town names.